# How to Query by line in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the query and table below, how do I select the 1st line of each category of column TeamboardId?

```
SELECT * FROM Job WHERE HandLingTimeSeconds = '60'
```

| JobId | TeamboardId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

The expected result should be

| JobId | TeamboardId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

Comment: Can you please tag the DBMS you're using and it's version

Comment: If the data always has this form or if you always want to get the lowest JobId per TeamboardId, just write SELECT MIN (JobId), TeamboardId FROM job GROUP BY TeamboardId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use a window function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` like in the below query :

```
WITH j AS
(
 SELECT Job.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeamboardId ORDER BY JobId) AS rn 
   FROM Job
  WHERE HandLingTimeSeconds = '60'
)
SELECT *
  FROM j
 WHERE rn = 1
```